# Select all Users related to Company

Tags: sql, select

First of all, sorry for the meaningless title. Couldn't think of anything better. Please, take a look at my following tables:

User

```
+-----+-------+---------------+
|  id | name  | email         |
+-----+-------+---------------+
|   1 | NameA | namea@srv.com |
|   2 | NameB | nameb@srv.com |
|   3 | NameC | namec@srv.com |
+-----+-------+---------------+
```

Department

```
+-----+---------+-------+---------+
|  id | company | name  | manager |
+-----+---------+-------+---------+
|   1 |       1 | DeptA |       1 |
|   2 |       1 | DeptB |       2 |
+-----+---------+-------+---------+
```

Company

```
+-----+------+-------+
|  id | name | owner |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 | Buzz |     3 |
+-----+-------+------+
```

I need to find all users related to a Company. Something like:

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | company_id |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          1 |
|       2 |          1 |
|       3 |          1 |
+---------+------------+
```

How can I do that? I read about the different kind of joins (inner, outer, full, etc), but I couldn't figure out how to handle that "Department" table in the middle of everything.

Comment: In the example data shown, it appears that the only users shown are department managers or company owners, and are all in the User table.  There is no information shown for users who are (non-manager) members of a department.  Was this your intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with two queries:

```
select Department.manager as user_id, Company.id
from Company
join Department on Department.company=Company.id

union

select Company.owner as user_id, Company.id
from Company
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, Blorgbeard, but your suggestion is pretty similar to what I've being trying. The problem is that the 3rd result (in the example) doesn't show up. I need to find the user if he is the owner of the Company as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select User.id, User.name, User.email, CASE WHEN User.id = Company.Owner THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as CompanyOwner
from User
inner join Department on User.DepartmentID = Department.id
inner join Company on Company.id = Department.company
```

I think you're missing an entitiy relationship between Users and Departments, perhaps a departmentID on the User Table.  I think that might be the part you're missing.

Comment: All the relationships are there. Just not easy to "select", so to speak. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. Maybe I'll re-think my model.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would have some way to link Users to the Department they work in.  Either with a DeptID column added onto the User table.  In this example, the owner's department is represented as null, while the department of managers is populated, but which way you do this is up to you.

```
 User
+-----+-------+---------------+------+
|  id | name  | email         | dept |
+-----+-------+---------------+------+
|   1 | NameA | namea@srv.com |    1 |
|   2 | NameB | nameb@srv.com |    2 |
|   3 | NameC | namec@srv.com |  +++ |   
|   4 | NameD | named@srv.com |    2 |
|   5 | NameE | namee@srv.com |    2 |
+-----+-------+---------------+------+
```

So to get the list of all company 1 users where the department is populated on the User table, this becomes simple

```
SELECT u.id       as user_id,
       d.company  as company_id
  FROM User u
  INNER JOIN Department d   ON u.dept=d.id
  WHERE d.company=1

UNION

SELECT owner  as user_id,
       id     as company_id
  FROM Company
```

If you chose not to populate manager's department in the User table, you would have to append a UNION for that part as well, similar in construct to the first part directly above.

**Or** you might instead have an association table to show which employees work for which department.  This might be needed if a person could work in more than one department.  (The managers and owners might not need to be in this table, since they are already accounted for.  Again, up to you.  But if you do include them, then you wont need the UNIONs, so it will keep things simpler.  You might even put the owner in an "OWNERSHIP" department.)

```
 UserDept
+--------+--------+
| UserID | DeptID |
+--------+--------+
|    4   |    2   |
|    5   |    2   |
+--------+--------+

SELECT u.id       as user_id,
       d.company  as company_id
  FROM UserDept u
  INNER JOIN Department d   ON u.dept=d.id
  WHERE d.company=1
```

(Add UNIONs on as needed, if you did not include owners / managers in the UserDept table.)

But in case you need a deeper example, let's suppose you also needed the name from the User table:

```
SELECT u.id       as user_id,
       d.company  as company_id,
       u.name     as user_name
  FROM User u
  INNER JOIN UserDept x     ON u.id=x.user
  INNER JOIN Department d   ON x.dept=d.id
  WHERE d.company=1
```

Comment: As I commented in @discGolfJay answer, I'm starting to think about remodeling my entities. The first cause of this issue is that I'd like to create users first, not tying them to any department or company. Maybe it's time to refine that model and create this relationship from day-0. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Starting out with the best model for your application is always a good idea. ;-)